# Redux Saga Error: takeLatest$1 requires a pattern or channel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, redux-saga

I am using Redux and Redux Saga for my project of an online shopping website, so this is how I have done:

`actions/products.js`

```
export const Types = {
  GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST: 'products/get_products_request',
  GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS: 'products/get_products_success',
  CREATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST: 'products/create_product_request',
};

export const getProductRequest = () => ({
  type: Types.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
});

export const getProductSuccess = ({products}) => ({
  type: Types.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: {
    products,
  },
});

export const createProductRequest = ({
  name,
  price,
  description,
  productImage,
}) => ({
  type: Types.CREATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  payload: {
    name,
    price,
    description,
    productImage,
  },
});
```

`reducers/products.js`

```
import {Types} from '../actions/products';

const INTIAL_STATE = {
  products: [],
  error: '',
};

export default function products(state = INTIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload.products,
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

`reducers/index.js`

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import ProductsReducer from './products';
import OrderReducer from './orders';

export default combineReducers({
  products: ProductsReducer,
  orders: OrderReducer
});
```

`sagas/products.js`

```
import {takeEvery, call, fork, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as actions from '../actions/products';
import * as api from '../api/products';

function* getProducts() {
  try {
    const products = yield call(api.getProducts);
    // console.log(products);
    yield put(
      actions.getProductSuccess({
        products,
      })
    );
  } catch (e) {}
}

function* watchGetProductRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.Types.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST, getProducts);
}

function* createProduct({name, price, description, productImage}) {
  try {
    yield call(api.createProduct, {
      name,
      price,
      description,
      productImage,
    });
    yield call(getProducts);
    console.log('create products');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e, 'create products');
  }
}

function* watchCreateNewProductRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(actions.Types.CREATE_USER_REQUEST, createProduct);
}

const userSagas = [
  fork(watchGetProductRequest),
  fork(watchCreateNewProductRequest),
];

export default userSagas;
```

`sagas/index.js`

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import ProductsReducer from './products';
import OrderReducer from './orders';

export default combineReducers({
  products: ProductsReducer,
  orders: OrderReducer,
});
```

`api/products`

```
const baseUrl = 'https://shop-test-api.herokuapp.com';

export const getProducts = async () => {
  return await (await (await fetch(`${baseUrl}/products`)).json()).docs;
};

export const createProduct = async ({
  name,
  price,
  description,
  productImage,
}) => {
  return await fetch(`${baseUrl}/products`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      name,
      price,
      description,
      productImage,
    },
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  }).json();
};
```

even I have not import `createNewProductRequest` in the `actions/products.js` to the component I want to use, the console log out this error:

[image]

[image]

The error occurs in the function `createProduct` of `sagas/products.js`, I use `takeLastest` because I use many dispatches (create new product then take the updated product list after new product was created)
and it show me that error

please help me to tackle with it, it means a lot to me.

This is the code repo: https://gitlab.com/Khangithub/redux-saga-multiple-reducers-and-requests

Once again. thank you so much and have a good day

Comment: What is `actions.Types.CREATE_USER_REQUEST ` I think the problem is that that is not a string. At the moment it seems to be undefined, you have `GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST`, `GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` and `CREATE_PRODUCT_REQUEST`

Comment: I wonder if there was some recent change because there are multiple questions like this from today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472447/takeevery1-requires-a-pattern-or-channel-react-native

Answer (score 13):

Well, for me my action type was undefined, I changed the original file where I defined the types and forgot to effect the changes in my saga, hence that error. So that might be the same issue with your code. Just check your types to make sure its defined and there's no typos.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error because I had a duplicate name across sagas